# Apache is working but wont connect to localhost ..why?

Tags: apache

Just installed xampp and started all services including Apache but still somehow cannot connect to my localhost server still when i write the address 127.0.0.1 it shows that message that it works.
Someone with an idea whats happening

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: Do you mean that `http://localhost` does not work, but `http://127.0.0.1` does work?  What is the *exact* error msg?

Comment: yeah the address 127.0.0.1 works it says it works but the localhost doesnt i have to manually write the address down

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows or Linux (eg., Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, etc.)?

If you are using Windows 7/8/10, it should work without this steps, but do the following if not working with these Operating Systems:
1) Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2) Type notepad, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3) Click on *File*, click *Open*, go to **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc** and click on the **hosts** file.
4) Add the following (if not exists) at the end of the file or the start of the file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

5) Click Save, and it should work without any restart.

If you are using Linux, do the following:
1) Open the Terminal, type nano /etc/hosts
2) Add the following (if not exists):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

3) Now, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The above should solve your problem, but if not, please let me know.